# Django Rest Framework serializer check if exists in related Many to Many fiield

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a custom User model with a `blocked` field as

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    blocked = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="blocked_by", blank=True)
```

and I'm trying to have a serializer where I can look up a user by their ID and find out if they are blocked or not by the logged in user

my current is serializer

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_blocked = serializers.BooleanField() # need to populate this

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'user_type', 'is_blocked']
```

and my view

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

I'm just not sure how to populate that value such that it'd be true if the inquiried user is in the `blocked` manyToMany field of the logged in user or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and calculate it. Get the authenticated user and check if the serialized user is in the blocked list.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_blocked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'user_type', 'is_blocked']

    def get_is_blocked(self, obj):
        # you might need to do some fixes in this method, I'm not 100% sure that it works like you want
        logged_in_user = self.context['request'].user  # the authenticated user
        is_blocked = logged_in_user.blocked.filter(id=obj.id).exists()  # check if the serialized user (obj) is in the auth user blocked list
        return is_blocked
```

Comment: That is perfect thanks ! I totally forgot about `SerializerMethodField`